# Automatic whitespace in python

Tags: indentation, filetype-python

I'm a novice in Vim and configuring it for writing python scripts comfortably.

Is the a way to automatically put four spaces after I jump onto the first line of `while True:` loop ?

Comment: Adding `set autoindent` and `set cindent` to your vimrc should do the trick.

Comment: It works with c code but not with python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to have this setting:

```
" ---- Minimal configuration:
set smartindent   " Do smart autoindenting when starting a new line
set shiftwidth=4  " Set number of spaces per auto indentation
set expandtab     " When using <Tab>, put spaces instead of a <tab> character

" ---- Good to have for consistency
" set tabstop=4   " Number of spaces that a <Tab> in the file counts for
" set smarttab    " At <Tab> at beginning line inserts spaces set in shiftwidth

" ---- Bonus for proving the setting
" Displays '-' for trailing space, '>-' for tabs and '_' for non breakable space
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:-,nbsp:_
set list
```

**Minimal configuration**

`smartindent` is the option for automatically indenting when starting a new line. Note that a new line after a line starting with a keyword from `cinwords` is automatically indented. That means, whatever the file type is, a new indentation is done after lines starting by `while`,`for`...

`shiftwidth` sets the number of "spaces" when doing a smart indentation. Note that it will add as much tab characters as possible then the number of spaces needed (so if you set tab as eight space long and `shiftwidth` to 12, it will put one tab character and four spaces). In your case you want to set it to 4.

`expandtab` is the option for putting space instead of tab characters.

See:

- `:h smartindent`
- `:h cinwords`
- `:h shiftwidth`
- `:h expandtab`

**Good to have for consistency**

`tabstop` sets the number of "spaces" a tab corresponds. By default it is set to 8 (GNU convention). You want to consider a tab as 4 spaces.

`smarttab` corresponds to the behaviour when you insert a tab in a empty line. If it is set on: it will insert blanks according to `shiftwidth`, when off: according to `tabstop` or `softtabstop`. You want it to be set on.

See:

- `:h tabstop`
- `:h softtabstop`
- `:h smarttab`

**Bonus**

`listchars` defines the display for different type of characters. In our case: tab are displayed `>-` (`-` is repeated for filling the size the tab takes), trailing characters are displayed `-` and non-breakable space are displayed as `_`. With this settings, you can see the difference between tabs and spaces. `list` is set to activate the option.

See:

- `:h listchars`
- `:h 'list'`

**Further reading**

- [Converting tabs to spaces (Vimwiki)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces)
- [Tabs and Spaces (Vimcasts)](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/)